# Use javascript to force a textarea to scroll to end

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm making an instant chat service using PHP and Async javascript. Messages are taken from a database and placed into a text area. The problem is that when messages require the textarea to scroll the setInterval() function used to check and grab new messages forces the text area back to the top of its scrolling height.

I've seen a few solutions and none have worked so far. I tried setting the scrollTop to equal the scrollHeight, but to no avail.

Here's some code:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    if(getUrlVars()['to'] != null)
        setInterval(GetMessages, 1000);
}

function ToServer(cmd, data)
{
    xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlObj.open('POST','handler.php',true);
    xmlObj.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlObj.send(cmd + data);
    xmlObj.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status == 200)
        {
            if(cmd == 'cmd=push')
            {
                document.getElementById('pushResponse').innerHTML = xmlObj.responseText;
            }
            if(cmd == 'cmd=pop')
            {
                document.getElementById('messages').value += xmlObj.responseText;
            }

        }
    }
}

function GetMessages()
{
    // Grab account hash from auth cookie
    aHash = readCookie('privateChat');
    to = getUrlVars()['to'];
    ToServer('cmd=pop','&account=' + aHash + '&to=' + to);
    textArea = document.getElementById('messages');
    textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Private Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Conversation with {%RECIPIENT%}</h2>
        <div id="fieldContainer">
            <textarea col="10" rows="5" name="messageBox" id="messages"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <legend>Message</legend>
        <div id="fieldContainer">
            <input type="text" id="msgBox">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="fSend" value="Send message" onClick="SendMessage();">
    </div>
    <div id="pushResponse">Response</div>

    <script src="Chat.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a `<textarea>`? Chat consists of a large output, and a static field for input at the bottom.

Comment: Why not use a text area? It's an HTML form element for multiple lines of text, no? What else should I use?

Comment: How about using a scrollable DIV?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know they existed.

Comment: Lee Taylor, thanks a lot. This works perfectly with the scrollTop = scrollHeight line.

Comment: @Lee A text-area is for text *input*. The scrollable area of a chat application is *output*, not input. The input area is a fixed-height, one-line field at the bottom. Use a `<div>` for the output, and a `<input type="text">` for the input.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying Sime. Now I have another problem -_-